# Get ajaxForm response value

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I have this ajaxForm:

```
$('.simple-checkout').ajaxForm({
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("Success");
    $('.cart-value').load(location.href);
},
error: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    alert("Error");
}
});
```

Console log looks like this:

> {success: true, data: {…}}
>   data
>   :
>   action
>   :
>   "create_ajax_checkout"
>   add-to-cart
>   :
>   "530"
>   order_date
>   :
>   "2018-02-13, kedd"
>   quantity
>   :
>   "1"
>   thwepof_product_fields
>   :
>   "order_date"
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object
>   success
>   :
>   true
>   **proto**
>   :
>   Object

my question is can I get the `response`'s quantity somehow?

Comment: What did you mean as 'response's quantity'?

Comment: @MaximSarandi `response` contains that string. And I need the quantity value from that.

Answer (score 0):

[length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) might help yous.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756104/get-size-of-json-object) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40625144/how-to-find-the-length-of-a-json-object).